# Buddypress adding change avatar link

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have already allowed users to upload avatars in the plugin settings as Admin. 
In the user profile editing page i dont see the Change avatar link, but i can access it thought `/members/myname/profile/change-avatar/` and i can upload avatar with no problems.

Also i have edited the `/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/members/single/profile/edit.php` and tried to add
`<a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>profile/change-avatar">Change Avatar</a>` but i see no changes in the edit profile page.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should start by creating a Buddypress child theme. Similarly to Wordpress child themes, they allow you to customise what you need, however, these changes don't get lost when you update your Buddypress plugin.

For info on this see [Building a Child Theme of the BP Default Theme](http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/building-a-buddypress-child-theme/).

Then go about updating your child theme files and come back here if you still have the same issue.